# How does TOTP work if I need to store the OTP in DB?

Tags: java, one-time-password, totp

I have a requirement

1. A third party provider (TPP) wants to access a Rest Endpoint using an OTP.
2. So TPP requests a service1 which in turn calls a service2 which generates an OTP, stores user specific data related to this request in DB against that OTP and returns the OTP to the TPP. These OTPs are valid for some n time sy for e.g . 6 minutes. So far so good, Now my questions below
3. I can only generate 6 digits OTPs. I am using Java.Crypto.mac. I am getting many duplicate OTPs. What is the best Algorithm so that the probability of getting duplicates is reduced. I took hint from https://github.com/jchambers/java-otp/blob/master/src/main/java/com/eatthepath/otp/HmacOneTimePasswordGenerator.java

using same logic. I tested using jmeter for single thread,5000 times I am getting almost 500 duplicate  OTPs

2. I have read that TOTP works in a client server approach. I don't understand in my scenario there is no client as such. Is there a way that I do not store the OTP in DB?
3. Also at some point all the OTPs would be exhausted if I keep them in DB.

I have read almost all the articles about XOR128,TOTP,HOTP but there is something that I am missing to understand. Please help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I see several possible approaches.

The first one is TOTP, you don't need to store OTPs at all, all you need is storing a secret key, that will be used to generate OTP.

The second option (commonly used) is to provide your clients with an API key and each time they send a request they need to generate access key using some hash algorithm. The source for hash function should be a string which contains API key and current time step. 
Here is an API instruction from one of the top OTP providers, you can find an example of described approach on page 5 "Authorization": https://www.protectimus.com/images/pdf/Protectimus_API_Manual_en.pdf